# Openlayers views , center map to each geofield

Tags: views, javascript

I have setting geofield in profile for each user , and make a view that list the location of the current user post (" I'm here ") , but the map isn't centered well to show up the marker , and when you zoom out it shows the markers.

So how do I get my map centered for each user geofield ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go to /admin/structure/openlayers/maps
2. Choose the map you are using to display your geofield on the user
3. Select the behaviors tab
4. Check off Zoom to Layer
5. Select geofield_formatter
6. Enter your zoom level

[image]

Note: If I misunderstood your question, and you were actually referring to centering on the markers on your view that compiled all of the users, then just select your view name in the 'Zoom to Layer'.

Comment: awesome, I am alos looking for this.